# How to add attribute Priority to SLD for GeoServer style

Tags: geoserver, style, sld

I tried to add Priority attribute to SLD Style on GeoServer, but i got the following error

**line 186: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.opengis.net/sld":Priority}'. One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/ogc":expression}' is expected.**

SLD file

```
      <se:TextSymbolizer>
        <se:Label>
          <ogc:PropertyName>name_en</ogc:PropertyName>
          <Priority>
            <ogc:PropertyName>priority</ogc:PropertyName>
          </Priority>
        </se:Label>
       ...
      </se:TextSymbolizer>
```

Comment: there is no need to paste in the entire 200 lines of sld

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your SLD:

1. `Priority` is an [element](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/reference/labeling.html#geoserver-enhanced-options) of the `TextSymbolizer` not the `Label` so you've added it in the wrong place.
2. By not using a prefix on your XML elements you have switched versions of styling language from Symbolology Encodeing (SE or SLD2) back to the default of Styled Layer Description (SLD) so if you change the XML to be valid:

   ```
   <se:TextSymbolizer>
      <se:Label>
        <ogc:PropertyName>name_en</ogc:PropertyName>
      </se:Label>
      <se:Priority>
        <ogc:PropertyName>priority</ogc:PropertyName>
      </se:Priority>
      ....
    </se:TextSymbolizer>
   ```